# Error in Installation of SSDT 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I am having problem with installation of SSDT 2012. Problem:

> VS shell 2012 has failed with exit code -2147205120

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible causes. See if any of these solutions help.

- Install [VS 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305) first (or the [latest update for VS 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2707250/overview-of-visual-studio-2012-updates)).
- If .NET Framework 4.5 is not yet installed then [install it manually](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653) before SSDT.
- Install these before SSDT: [Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38807), [Visual Studio 2012 Shell Isolated](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30670)
- Check the amount of free space left on the hard drive.
- Check the SSDT [system requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36843).